# getContext().getContentResolver() may produce NullPointerException

Tags: android, contentprovider

Android Studio выдаёт следующее предупреждение при наведении на `getContext().getContentResolver()` внутри класса, унаследованного от `ContentProvider`-a:

> getContext().getContentResolver() may produce NullPointerException

А в действительности может ли такое произойти? Ведь, насколько я понимаю, `ContentProvider` сам ответственен за предоставление контекста, т.е., такого никогда случиться не должно?.. Или же всё-таки есть какие-то случаи, и стоит делать проверку на `null` перед вызовом метода `getContentResolver()` у контекста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getContext()` может быть `null`, если его вызвать до вызова метода onCreate